# Creating a view with unique records

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, cube

I have a question about the following view. Below is the code.

```
select

   pe.project_id
  ,pe.project_evenement_id
  ,pes.project_evenement_sponsor_id
  ,peu.project_evenement_uitgave_post_id
  ,pe.omschrijving
  ,pes.bedrag as 'project sponsor bedrag'
  ,peu.bedrag as 'project evenement bedrag'

from  project_evenement pe

left join  project_evenement_sponsor pes
  on    pes.project_id = pe.project_id
  and   pes.project_evenement_id = pe.project_evenement_id

left join  project_evenement_uitgave_post peu
   on    peu.project_id = pe.project_id
   and   peu.project_evenement_id = pe.project_evenement_id
```

I want to create unique records, but the result shows duplicates. Can someone tell me how to solve this issue. I am getting much more records then I supposed to.

[I added a photo of the datamodel and output to paint a better picture of the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2FsO.png)

Comment: Hint:  `select distinct`.

Comment: This could be because of One to Many relationship or you are missing Join predicates. As mentioned by Gordan `Distinct` can fix the problem but is that the right fix, that can be decided only by knowing the table relationships

Answer (score 0):

Add ",*" to the SELECT (just before the FROM). That will show all columns and you can see where the duplicates are and then adjust the join conditions (add more conditions to eliminate the duplicates) or, if that is not possible, add DISTINCT after the SELECT.